# is possible to make microsoft LUIS auto trained with API?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

last time i try to learn about LUIS from microsoft, and i found some interesting part about train LUIS.

Is Possible to trained Microsoft LUIS using API without login to LUIS Dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible through [LUIS programmatic APIs](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56d95961e597ed0f04b76e58/operations/56f8a55119845511c81de483)
There are 2 APIs:

- Train : Asynchronously firing the train request for your App `[POST]https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/{appId}/train`
- Training Status : to check the training status `[Get]https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/{appId}/train`

You will need to provide the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header, which is the  Subscription key that provides access to the API.

Comment: it's the same LUIS in projectoxford and common use for user?

Comment: Yes, of course. The URL looks a bit different because Microsoft used to groups cognitive services under one umbrella called project oxford.

Comment: can you please help me with the :
`[POST]https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/{appId}/publish`
the publish operation dont work for me , i got a 400 bad argument with no further explanation ... , there is any special manipulation with this operation ?

Comment: An invalid appId could cause that.